# Can't log into POP3 account using Exim/Dovecot mail server (debian)

Tags: debian, connection, exim, pop3, dovecot

I'm trying to set up a mail server for our dedicated server, and the only thing remaining that doesn't work is the POP login. The outlook dialog box just keep asking me for the right user name/password.
Here's the output from `tailf -f /var/log/syslog`:

```
Jul  8 11:06:48 newserverxxxx dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: rip=93.97.xxx.xxx, lip=94.76.xxx.xxx
```

Information:

1. The User does exist, and I can log on
2. All the other steps works (SMTP, and mail test)
3. And I can even send mails to other addresses from the server or a mail() call

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Comment: how do you have dovecot configured? Local users? Mysql backend? What port is dovecot listening on? Are you using any kind of encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the `pop3-login` process in your logfile means it seems configured. So I suggest to enable authentication debugging:

`grep -e 'auth_verbose' -e 'auth_debug' /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` (set these two to "yes" and restart dovecot).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I configured the debug parameters, and here are the results: 
`Jul 22 12:59:46 newserverxxxx dovecot: pop3-login: Login failed: Plaintext authentication disabled: rip=93.97.xxx.xxx, lip=94.76.xxx.xxx
Jul 22 12:59:46 newserverxxxx dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: rip=93.97.xxx.xxx, lip=94.76.xxx.xxx
Jul 22 12:59:46 newserverxxxx dovecot: auth(default): new auth connection: pid=25600` 
It looks like the plain text login authentication is disabled, but when I check dovecot.conf, the disabling line is commented and the plain is authorised in the default settings

Comment: So, I tried to uncomment the line : disable_plaintext_auth = yes, and then turned it into: disable_plaintext_auth = no. and IT WORKS! Thank you for the verbose suggestion. Nicolas.

Answer (score 0):

Try the full email address as the user name (johnsmith@example.com or johnsmith+example.com)

Hosted servers often require the entire email address to distinguish between the same user name on multiple domains.  You may have configured POP to require disambiguation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work neither.